# Using .htaccess to redirect anything that's not the current directory or a file in it

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Since yesterday I tried to make a rewriterule in `.htaccess` to do the next things:

> SITE.TDL = EXCEPTION
>   SITE.TDL/file.ext = EXCEPTION
>   SITE.TDL/anythingElse = REDIRECTED

The most I've come to is the next code, but it doesen't seems to work... the second rulle only applies to that files, but I don't want tu manually include every file...

```
RewriteRule  ^/ /index.php [L,NC]                                                                                                                                                                             
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|x\.php|api\.php|robots\.txt|humans\.txt|style\.css)                                                                                                                                                                              
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://gome.tk/x.php?x=$1 [r=301,nc]
```

I simply cannot find a way to make it work... Please, help me!
Edit: I know I could simply include an exception in `x.php` for when `$_GET["x"]==""`, or use the rewrite rule with, let's say, the *virtual* folder `x`, and just rewrite everything to the next line, but I want to keep the link as short as possible...
    `rewriterule ^x/(.*)$ /x.php?x=$1`

Thank you for your time!

Comment: what you mean "EXCEPTION"? Is it "forbidden" or "not found"?

Comment: I mean the rewriteRule is not applied to that one(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://gome.tk/x.php?x=$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks! Now it works perfectly! I'll add what I used as an answer to my question, for the case when someone wants to do the same thing.

Comment: After some testing and the help of these people and other sites, I found out what I needed to use:
Options +FollowSymlinks  
________RewriteEngine on  
________RewriteRule  ^$ - [L,NC]  
________RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
________RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://gome.tk/x.php?x=$1 [L,r=301]

Comment: <pre>____`-` = (as in the first RewriteRule, for example) means that the links matching that rule won't be changed
____for the rest of the meanings, you could visit the last link
____`L` = That is the last rule for the links that match that conditions  
____`R` = Causes a redirect. The number value of the R says the code of the redirect meant  
____`NC` = NoCaps. In other words, Case Insensitive  
</pre> 
____<http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html>  
____<http://www.webforgers.net/mod-rewrite/mod-rewrite-syntax.php>

Comment: I just should have added this before the RewriteCond line: `RewriteRule  ^$ - [L,NC]` . Thank you!

Comment: @SapioiT this rule is meaningless, as finally it may get the directory index. Use [`DirectoryIndex`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your first rule isn't going to work because the URI has its leading slash stripped off. Your rules should look like this:

```
RewriteRule  ^$ /index.php [L,NC]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|x\.php|api\.php|robots\.txt|humans\.txt|style\.css)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://gome.tk/x.php?x=$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: but how could I replace the second line, I mean the RewriteCond, so that I don't have to manually enter the file names of the first directory? I tried with replacing the round brackets with -f but that will not work properly, rewriting anything (which includes the x.php file to x.php?x=x.php and that one to x.php?x=x.php and so on)
<code>
 RewriteRule  ^$ /index.php [L,NC]
 RewriteCond $1 ^(-f)$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://gome.tk/x.php?x=$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: *RewriteCond $1 !^(-f)$* replaces nothing ________
    *RewriteCond $1 ^(-f)$* replaces everything in a loop

Comment: Too tired of waiting to make a complete answer with more details...
http://pastebin.com/iLrsf0A1

Comment: Looks like I've been banned for just asking a question... and I already wrote an answer to another question (and I cannot send it)...